# Ler dados potenciometro do arduino para o android

Tags: android, arduino

Tenho um sketch de arduino que hoje me permite acender e apagar leds via bluetooth com um app que desenvolvi no eclipse para android.

Agora estou tentando capturar o valor de um potênciomêtro, conforme se altera o seu valor, isso pode ser feito via `inputStream( )` ? E se não pode como deve ser feito ?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste link, acho que ele já está bem completo e pode esclarecer bem suas dúvidas: http://www.arduinoecia.com.br/2014/01/enviando-dados-do-arduino-para-o.html

Comment: Jorge, você poderia dar mais detalhes? Assim podemos ajudar melhor, respondendo pontualmente qual o problema. Pelo visto, parece que lhe falta o código para ler o potenciometro no Arduino, e não no Android correto?

Comment: @regmoraes, seria interessante você construir uma resposta mais detalhada e abrangendo para que possamos contribuir com  a melhoria na participação da comunidade Arduino no site. Usando o recurso responder abaixo.